# React-Navigation with Redux : Getting error when using back arrow to go to previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

The navigation is working alright otherwise and i am able to navigate between screens but when I use the back arrow (on the header) it gives me following error [image]

Comment: can you share some code

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the back button in a seperate class which you dont pass the navigation object to?
If you code looks something like

```
export default class myClass extends React.Component{
 render(){
  return (
   <View>
    <View> whatever </View>
    <BackButton />
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```

make sure to pass naviation to your backbutton in order to execute navigation.dispatch on it. So it should look like:

```
<BackButton navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Comment: solved it. Actually I hadn't included dispatch in addNavigationHelper of StackNavigator.